# How to treat apostrophe and right single quotation mark as the same character?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, full-text-search

My database has stored some text that used the apostrophe and the various single quotation marks carelessly and interchangeably.

I now have to do a search function. What's the trick to match the apostrophe with the apostrophe and the various quotation marks, if not all then at least the right single quotation mark?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REPLACE`, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @table table (Value varchar(255))

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('’'), ('‘'), ('''')

SELECT *
FROM @table
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(Value, '’', ''''), '‘', '''') LIKE '%''%'
```